# Strip common indentation from the beginning of each line similar to what pydoc help does with docstrings

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a module `foo` (in foo.py) with a function `f` defined in this manner.

```
def f():
    """Test

    Line 1
    Line 2
    """
    pass
```

This is the how the docstring appears in an interactive session.

```
>>> print(foo.f.__doc__)

Test

    Line 1
    Line 2

>>> help(foo.f)
Help on function f in module foo:

f()
    Test

    Line 1
    Line 2

>>>
```

As, you can see the `help()` function takes care of removing common indentation from the beginning of each line while displaying the help. I want to write my own function that does something similar.

For example, if

```
s = """Foo

    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
"""
```

Then `my_function(s)` should return

```
"""Foo

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3"""
```

Is there anything in the Python standard library that can help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`textwrap.dedent()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent):

```
import textwrap

def my_function(s):
    first, *rest = s.splitlines(keepends=True) # the first line is special
    return first + textwrap.dedent(''.join(rest))
```

Example:

```
>>> my_function(s)
'Foo\n\nLine 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n'
```

Note: the final newline is not stripped.